# How to print java.lang.Class object to a file?

Tags: class, java

I have tried looking for a way to compile a class on the fly and I have got as for as create a compiled Class instance. However, I want to be able to create a .class file that is executable. How would I, if possible, be able to output the Class object to a .class file. If this is incorrect, please explain how I would be able to do this.

Comment: can you be a bit clear , I am sorry but I fail to understand the question

Comment: What do you really mean by "create a class file that is executable"?  No class files are directly executable by the OS - a JVM is started and it then invokes the main method on a given class.

Comment: Class files are already executabele by `java` command. What exactly is your problem? Entering that long `java` command everytime? Just create a `.bat` or `.sh` file wherein you put that full command.

Comment: I'm looking at the words "compile a class on the fly" - I assumed you were generating a class file programatically from an existing program (ie byte code generation rather than using javac compiling source).  Is that the case?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Don't. Make an executable jar instead.

There are other options as outlined [here](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-to-exe.html), if you feel and executable jar is not what you need.

Answer (score 0):

This page http://www.accordess.com/wpblog/an-overview-of-java-compilation-api-jsr-199/  describes the process of compiling Java code from string, producing a .class file.  Here's an abbreviated version of that page's otherwise well-commented code.

```
public class CompilerAPITest {
    final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CompilerAPITest.class.getName()) ;

    /** Java source code to be compiled dynamically */
    static String sourceCode = "package com.accordess.ca;" +
        "class DynamicCompilationHelloWorld{" +
            "public static void main (String args[]){" +
                "System.out.println (\"Hello, dynamic compilation world!\");" +
            "}" +
        "}" ;

    /* Object initialization and compilation. */
    public void doCompilation (){
        SimpleJavaFileObject fileObject = new DynamicJavaSourceCodeObject ("com.accordess.ca.DynamicCompilationHelloWorld", sourceCode) ;
        JavaFileObject javaFileObjects[] = new JavaFileObject[]{fileObject} ;
        JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        StandardJavaFileManager stdFileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(null, Locale.getDefault(), null);
        Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits = Arrays.asList(javaFileObjects);
        //This example places the output files under bin folder.
        String[] compileOptions = new String[]{"-d", "bin"} ;
        Iterable<String> compilationOptions = Arrays.asList(compileOptions);
        DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics = new DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject>();
        CompilationTask compilerTask = compiler.getTask(null, stdFileManager, diagnostics, compilationOptions, null, compilationUnits) ;
        boolean status = compilerTask.call();
        if (!status){//If compilation error occurs
            for (Diagnostic diagnostic : diagnostics.getDiagnostics()){
                System.out.format("Error on line %d in %s", diagnostic.getLineNumber(), diagnostic);
            }
        }
        try {
            stdFileManager.close() ;//Close the file manager
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        new CompilerAPITest ().doCompilation() ;
    }
}

class DynamicJavaSourceCodeObject extends SimpleJavaFileObject{
    private String qualifiedName ;
    private String sourceCode ;

    protected DynamicJavaSourceCodeObject(String name, String code) {
        super(URI.create("string:///" +name.replaceAll("\\.", "/") + Kind.SOURCE.extension), Kind.SOURCE);
        this.qualifiedName = name ;
        this.sourceCode = code ;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getCharContent(boolean ignoreEncodingErrors)
            throws IOException {
        return sourceCode ;
    }
    // ... getters and setters
}
```